# "Clear All" shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA run console log

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, console

Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut to clear the console log in IntelliJ??
I have looked everywhere and I don't seem to find it
[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no default shortcut, you have to add it:

[image: add shortcut for clear all]

Comment: Is there any way to clear console upon deploying or running app?

Comment: What did you bind it to? I can't find a good key combination 

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to put the focus on the console before executing the shortcut 

Answer (score 0):

on mac you can do it with cmd + k

Comment: cmd + k opens the commit page

Comment: i believe you have to focus on terminal for the shortcut to work ?